equivalent expression of the uncertainty principle in the presence of quantum memory
I'm reading the paper The Uncertainty Principle in the Presence of Quantum Memory. In the appendix the authors say that expression (2) is equivalent to (3). However, R is a mapping performed on system A. Why should $H(RB)=H(RE)$ instead of $H(RB)=H(E)$?
